# Use result of two subqueries to calculate ratio

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have the query below

```
SELECT 'Active Borrowers per Loan Officer' AS PERFORMANCE_RATIOS,
    (
        SELECT count(DISTINCT L.CUSTOMER_ID) / COUNT(DISTINCT L.MIS_ACCT_OFFICER) AS RATIO
        FROM LD_LOANS_AND_DEPOSITS L
        WHERE REPORT_DATE = (
                SELECT MIN(REPORT_DATE)
                FROM LD_LOANS_AND_DEPOSITS
                )
        ) AS RATIO1,
    (
        SELECT count(DISTINCT L.CUSTOMER_ID) / COUNT(DISTINCT L.MIS_ACCT_OFFICER) AS RATIO
        FROM LD_LOANS_AND_DEPOSITS L
        WHERE REPORT_DATE = (
                SELECT MAX(REPORT_DATE)
                FROM LD_LOANS_AND_DEPOSITS
                )
        ) AS RATIO2,
    (
        (
            SELECT count(DISTINCT L.CUSTOMER_ID) / COUNT(DISTINCT L.MIS_ACCT_OFFICER) AS RATIO
            FROM LD_LOANS_AND_DEPOSITS L
            WHERE REPORT_DATE = (
                    SELECT MAX(REPORT_DATE)
                    FROM LD_LOANS_AND_DEPOSITS
                    )
            ) - (
            SELECT count(DISTINCT L.CUSTOMER_ID) / COUNT(DISTINCT L.MIS_ACCT_OFFICER) AS RATIO
            FROM LD_LOANS_AND_DEPOSITS L
            WHERE REPORT_DATE = (
                    SELECT MIN(REPORT_DATE)
                    FROM LD_LOANS_AND_DEPOSITS
                    )
            )
        ) / (
        SELECT count(DISTINCT L.CUSTOMER_ID) / COUNT(DISTINCT L.MIS_ACCT_OFFICER) AS RATIO
        FROM LD_LOANS_AND_DEPOSITS L
        WHERE REPORT_DATE = (
                SELECT MIN(REPORT_DATE)
                FROM LD_LOANS_AND_DEPOSITS
                )
        ) * 100 AS CHANGE,
    (
        SELECT MIN(REPORT_DATE)
        FROM LD_LOANS_AND_DEPOSITS
        ) AS REPORT_DATE1,
    (
        SELECT MAX(REPORT_DATE)
        FROM LD_LOANS_AND_DEPOSITS
        ) AS REPORT_DATE2
```

What I need to do is to use Ratio1/Ratio2 outside instead of having to repeat the whole sql code that returns theese 2 values. How do I do this?

Comment: just added it, apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer

```
SELECT PERFORMANCE_RATIOS, RATIO1, RATIO2, RATIO1 - RATIO2 AS SUBTRACT, RATIO1 * RATIO2 AS Multiply
FROM (
SELECT 'Active Borrowers per Loan Officer' AS PERFORMANCE_RATIOS,
    (
        SELECT count(DISTINCT L.CUSTOMER_ID) / COUNT(DISTINCT L.MIS_ACCT_OFFICER) AS RATIO
        FROM LD_LOANS_AND_DEPOSITS L
        WHERE REPORT_DATE = (
                SELECT MIN(REPORT_DATE)
                FROM LD_LOANS_AND_DEPOSITS
                )
        ) AS RATIO1,
    (
        SELECT count(DISTINCT L.CUSTOMER_ID) / COUNT(DISTINCT L.MIS_ACCT_OFFICER) AS RATIO
        FROM LD_LOANS_AND_DEPOSITS L
        WHERE REPORT_DATE = (
                SELECT MAX(REPORT_DATE)
                FROM LD_LOANS_AND_DEPOSITS
                )
        ) AS RATIO2
) Table
```